# WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: uniformMatrix4fv / [WebGL-00000A18072FEA00] GL_INVALID_OPERATION

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babylonjs, babel-babylon

I am currently developing an application that displays 360° images and I use the BabylonJS library for that.

I have a navbar that allows me to navigate between the different 360 locations. But as soon as I change the 360 ​​image via the navbar, I get these errors
repeat in my console.

Error:

> [.WebGL-00000A18072FEA00] GL_INVALID_OPERATION: Must have element array buffer bound.

> WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: uniformMatrix4fv: location is not from current program

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask] and take the [tour], then see if you can revise to provide more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of testing I finally found the problem and therefore the solution.
this is due to the fact that I had several scenes that overlapped. To solve this problem I simply deleted the previous scene before creating a new one.